# Saving a vector of Structs into a file and reading a vector of structs from a file in C++

Tags: c++, file, fstream

so i have a struct called person that contains different kind of variable (string,int,float,bool) and i created a vector of this struct. 
now i want to save this vector into a file so i can read it later.
and i have no idea how (i'm new to programming )

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

struct person {
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    int age;
    string adress;
    string id;
    string phoneNumber;
    float bodyTemperature;
    bool backgroundDisease;
    string  backgroundDiseaseInfo;
    string bloodType;  
    bool breathingStatus; // true for normal and false for unusual
    bool cough;
};


int main() 
{
    vector<person> database;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to save and custom objects, I can highly recommend the boost serialization library, see [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/serialization/doc/archives.html).

However, here is a solution without boost. Reading and writing of custom objects can be done overloading the stream operators `operator<<` and `operator>>`, which allows you to write and read data from a stream.

In the code below `ofstream(filename) out` defines an output file-stream, it therefore creates a file with name `filename` if it does not exist, yet. You can stream to it via `out << p`. Similarly `ifstream(filename)` opens an input file-stream. The full code below allows you to save and load `SimplePerson` data.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include<sstream>

struct SimplePerson {

    SimplePerson() = default;
    SimplePerson(const std::string &f, const std::string &l)
      :firstName(f), lastName(l) {}
    std::string firstName;
    std::string lastName;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const SimplePerson &p)
{
    out << p.firstName << ' ' << p.lastName;
    return out;
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &in, SimplePerson &p)
{
    in >> p.firstName >> p.lastName;
    return in;
}

void save(const std::vector<SimplePerson> &database, const std::string &filename)
{
    std::ofstream out(filename);
    if(out.is_open())
        for(const auto &p : database)
        {
            out << p << '\n';
        }
    else
        std::cout << "error opening file" << std::endl;
}

void load(std::vector<SimplePerson> &database, const std::string &filename)
{
    std::ifstream in(filename);
    std::string line;

    SimplePerson p;
    while(getline(in, line))
    {
        std::istringstream iss(line);
        iss >> p;
        database.push_back(p);
    }
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<SimplePerson> original = {SimplePerson{"a","b"}, 
         SimplePerson{"c","d"}};
    save(original,"database.txt");

    std::vector<SimplePerson> restored;
    load(restored,"database.txt");

    for (auto& p : restored)
        std::cout << p << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**I also highly recommend you to get a good book and study the basics**